# How to convert an audio file from one format to another?

Tags: conversion, file-format

I have an audio file named with such properties:

`BreakingNews.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz`

I wanted to convert it to this format:

`BreakingNews.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711 A-law, mono 8000 Hz`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://superuser.com/questions/823049/change-codec-of-wav-file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a pcm_mulaw output.wav
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try & update you. @purplepsycho